# Strange behavior of the function pow() in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I have stupid problem with pow() in my application. Here is the code:

```
double xf = 0.0153846154;

NSLog(@"%.10f", xf);
if (abs(xf) < (5.0 * pow(10.0, -9.0))) {
    NSLog(@"%.10f", 5.0 * pow(10.0, -9.0));
}
```

but if I try this one comparation is correct:

```
if (abs(xf) >= pow(10.0, 10.0)) {
    NSLog(@"%f", pow(10.0, 10.0));
}
```

and my Log is:

```
2012-10-13 15:45:24.587 myApp[22941:c07] 0.0153846154
2012-10-13 15:45:28.950 myApp[22941:c07] 0.0000000050
```

Can someone explains me why is 0.0153846154 < 0.0000000050

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[abs](http://linux.die.net/man/3/abs) is an integer function so `xf` gets truncated to `0`, so the function result is `0`, which then gets cast back to `0.0` for the comparison.

You need to use [fabs](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fabs):

```
NSLog(@"%.10f", xf);
if (fabs(xf) < (5.0 * pow(10.0, -9.0))) {
    NSLog(@"%.10f", 5.0 * pow(10.0, -9.0));
}
```